# Merge two arrays into one with unique values, and change the id key

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays of objects, the objects within these arrays have a slightly different keys but share same id.

What i am trying to do is merge these two arrays into one that contains all the elements from both without duplicates.

array one:

```
[
   {id: 'ABC_123', value: 10, label: 'tree', level: 'mid'},
   {id: 'ABC_456', value: 11, label: 'grass', level: 'top'}
];
```

array two:

```
[
   {levelId: 'ABC_123', value: 10, label: 'tree', level: 'mid'},
   {levelId: 'ABC_456', value: 11, label: 'grass', level: 'top'},
   {levelId: 'ABC_789', value: 11, label: 'bush', level: 'low'}
];
```

I want to bring all the new elements from array two into array one in this example i want element with `levelId: 'ABC_789` to move into array one and change the levelId key into id:

result:

```js
[
       {id: 'ABC_123', value: 10, label: 'tree', level: 'mid'},
       {id: 'ABC_456', value: 11, label: 'grass', level: 'top'}
       {id: 'ABC_789', value: 11, label: 'bush', level: 'low'}

]
```

I have tried mapping over them matching the id's and creating new array but I cant get the desired result

Comment: If an ID shows up in both arrays, are the values of the object guaranteed to be identical aside from `id`/`levelId`? And if not, how should that be handled?

Comment: I think lodash has a function for this. Regardless, how do you determine the order of the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over both structures.

I am using reduce as a loop structure and find acts as one too.

You essentially want to look through the possible new values and determine if it exists already in the first array. If it doesn't exist then push its value into array 1.. in this case a new object structure.

Here is a rough solution:

```
let arr1 = [
   {id: 'ABC_123', value: 10, label: 'tree', level: 'mid'},
   {id: 'ABC_456', value: 11, label: 'grass', level: 'top'}
];

let arr2 = [
   {levelId: 'ABC_123', value: 10, label: 'tree', level: 'mid'},
   {levelId: 'ABC_456', value: 11, label: 'grass', level: 'top'},
   {levelId: 'ABC_789', value: 11, label: 'bush', level: 'low'}
];


function mergeArr(a1, a2) {
    return a2.reduce((newArr, el) => {
      const has = a1.find((entry) => entry.id === el.levelId);

      if (!has) {
        newArr.push({
          id: el.levelId,
          value: el.value,
          label: el.label,
          level: el.level
        });
      }

      return newArr;
    }, a1)
}

console.log(mergeArr(arr1, arr2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could collect the `id` values from the first array, but them in a set, and iterate the second collection to select those that have no match in that set. With destructuring assignment you can achieve the change of `levelId` to `id`:

```js
// Your example input:
const a = [{id: 'ABC_123', value: 10, label: 'tree', level: 'mid'},{id: 'ABC_456', value: 11, label: 'grass', level: 'top'}];
const b = [{levelId: 'ABC_123', value: 10, label: 'tree', level: 'mid'},{levelId: 'ABC_456', value: 11, label: 'grass', level: 'top'},{levelId: 'ABC_789', value: 11, label: 'bush', level: 'low'}];

// Get the id values from the first array
const keys = new Set(a.map(({id}) => id));
// Select the items from the second array, and if their levelId is not in 
//    the set, add them to the first array:
for (const {levelId: id, ...rest} of b) {
    if (!keys.has(id)) a.push({id, ...rest});
}

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just initiate the result with `arr1`, then for each element in `arr2` check if already exist. If yes - ignore it, otherwise append to the result and change `levelId` to `id`:

```js
const arr1 = [
   {id: 'ABC_123', value: 10, label: 'tree', level: 'mid'},
   {id: 'ABC_456', value: 11, label: 'grass', level: 'top'}
];

const arr2 = [
   {levelId: 'ABC_123', value: 10, label: 'tree', level: 'mid'},
   {levelId: 'ABC_456', value: 11, label: 'grass', level: 'top'},
   {levelId: 'ABC_789', value: 11, label: 'bush', level: 'low'}
];

const merge = (arr1, arr2) => {
    const cachedIds = arr1.reduce((acc, value) => {
        return {
            ...acc,
            [value.id]: true
        };
    }, {});

    return arr2.reduce((acc, value) => {
        if (cachedIds[value.levelId]) {
            return acc;
        }

        const transformedObject = {
            id: value.levelId,
            ...value,
        }

        delete transformedObject.levelId;

        return [
            ...acc,
            transformedObject,
        ];
    }, arr1);
}

console.log(merge(arr1, arr2))
```

Assuming the length of the `array1` is `n` and length of `arr2` is `m`, this solution complexity is:

Run time: `O(m)`
Space: `O(n)`